Struggling to understand a few definitions relating to relativization in Chapter 12 of Jech's Set Theory
I have been struggling to understand relativization as introduced around page 162 in Jech's Set Theory. Below I try to go over an example in hopes someone can point out if I'm doing something wrong. Let me begin by some things I think are correct (please correct me if I'm wrong):

Given a formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are free variables and any theory $T$, we have that $T\vdash \phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ if and only if $T\vdash \forall x_1\ldots\forall x_n \phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

The formula $\phi^M$ is obtained from $\phi$ by adjoining the substring "$(x\in M)\land$" in front of every substring "$\exists x$" or "$\forall x$" in $\phi$.


Thus, for example, we have that
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(x\subseteq y) & \equiv \forall u\in x(u\in y)\\
(x\subseteq y)^M & \equiv \forall u\in x\cap M(u\in y).
\end{alignat*}
and because of $(1)$ we have that
$$(x\subseteq y)^M \iff \forall x\forall y\forall u\in x\cap M(u\in y).$$
Now, Lemma 12.9 from the book reads

Lemma 12.9. If $M$ is a transitive class and $\varphi$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula, then for all $x_1, \ldots, x_n$,
\begin{equation*}
    (12.18) \quad \varphi^M(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n).
\end{equation*}

and taking into account that $(x\subseteq y)$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula (see Lemma 12.10) we have that for transitive $M$
$$\forall x\forall y\forall u\in x(u\in y)\iff (x\subseteq y) \iff (x\subseteq y)^M \iff \forall x\forall y\forall u\in x\cap M(u\in y).$$

"and because of $(1)$ we have that
$(x\subseteq y)^M \iff \forall x\forall y\forall u\in x\cap M(u\in y).$" No, you are confusing equi-derivability with equivalence. We went over this exact issue in the comments here.

Point 2 has an error. In the case of $\forall x$, one needs to replace with $\forall x\; x\in M \to$, not $\forall x \; x\in M\land.$
Point 1 could be correct, but depends on conventions. Most proof systems allow derivability of open formulas and have this property, but it's possible to have a proof system where only sentences are derivable. In terms of semantics rather than syntax, while it is sometimes the convention that we allow truth (and hence semantic consequence)  for open formulas, and that it is equivalent to the truth of the universal closure, it is somewhat more common in my experience to disallow it and to only talk about truth under variable assignments.
But either way, what you can't do is infer $T\vdash \varphi\leftrightarrow \psi$ from "$T\vdash \varphi \iff T\vdash \psi$". Even for sentences, it's possible that neither $T\vdash \phi$, $T\vdash \psi$, nor $T\vdash \varphi\leftrightarrow\psi.$
In particular, $$(x\subseteq y)^M \iff \forall x\forall y\forall u\in x\cap M(u\in y)$$ is nonsense. Usually, if the free variables aren't the same on both sides of an equivalence, something is wrong. Here, the left-hand side is a formula in two variables while the right-hand side is a sentence that is (almost) always false: we take any $x$ with $x\cap M$ nonempty, $y=\emptyset$ and any $u\in x\cap M$ as a counterexample.

I see. What does $(x\subseteq y)$ mean then? I know how to evaluate its universal closure $\forall x\forall y(x\subseteq y)$ in any interpretation, but not how to evaluate $(x\subseteq y)$. That is, when does an interpretaton $I$ make $(x\subseteq y)$ true?

@Sam It's an open formula, so there is no notion of truth for it. It only can become true or false if you assign elements of the domain to $x$ and $y$, and then whether it's true or false depends on which elements you picked (at least that's my preferred definition/way of thinking about it) .

@Sam Think about it like this... what if we ask "is the equation $x+3 = 10$ true?" I would say "depends what $x$ is, if it's $7$, then yes, otherwise no". Someone else might say "no, it's not generally the case that $x+3=10$ for every $x$, so the equation is false". These are both coherent ways of using the words "true/false" and it's entirely a matter of convention which one to pick as the official way to define such terms (which is not to say that they're equivalent... you will need to build on these different definitions in different ways to fully develop the theory).
